# Meaning of word 'synonym' in the given context

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of *Synonym* in this context?

> Nowadays modern mobile users are very exigent – they want great,
>   unique Material design, in-app maps, fast and precise geolocation,
>   social (let’s use synonym – Facebook  ) sign-in and so on…

I didn't look up a dictionary because I already know what "synonym" means, but I can't fit that meaning to this context. I was expecting "let’s use app– Facebook".

Why does the author use the word "synonym"? What do they want to imply?

Comment: Have you looked up the word in the dictionary? Do you suspect that it has a specific alternate meaning in this context?

Comment: @Tashus - I didn't look up dicationary becasue I know synonyms means same word. But here is something different saying. I was expecting _let’s use app– Facebook _

Comment: Next time please explain in more detail why you find this or that phrase odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Users want **social sign-in**

Is almost synonymous to

> Users want **Facebook sign-in**

Because Facebook is the predominant social network.

Thus the author says:

> Users are very demanding nowadays. When a user selects a new app for his smartphone, he wants this app to have **a social network sign-in feature**. Oh, well, let's just use a synonym. He wants it to have **a Facebook sign-in feature**.